# Use Active Directory to populate Request.Credentials to access webservice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, active-directory

Is there a way to detect the AD credentials of a user and use them to create a NetworkCredential object that can be used to query a webservice? An excerpt of my code is below, basically I'm querying a GIS database through a webservice and the webservice requires Windows AD authentication.

Currently this is a manual process and so we just hardcode our own AD credentials into the variables up top and it works fine but I'd like the page the detect someone's AD credentials and use them to create the NetworkCredential object so we can have our internal customers use the page as well.

```
Public Function getJSON(ByVal url As String) As String

    Dim HTMLSource As String = ""
    Dim Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, password, domain)
    Dim Response As WebResponse = Request.GetResponse
    Dim SR As StreamReader
    SR = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream)
    HTMLSource = SR.ReadToEnd
    SR.Close()
    Return HTMLSource
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Let to user delegate his Kerberos credential to your server/service, extract that during authentication, impersonate and perform your request on behalf of the user.

Comment: How would we do that if this is implemented through an ASP.NET web page?

Comment: Have you configured IIS to perform Negotiate authentication with Kerberos? More over, set that machine account to delegable. Otherwise you won't receive any delegated credential.